# Multiple Carousels in one page

Tags: multiple-instances, bxslider

I have implemented bxslider in our site where slider has been coming in dynamic way like in while loop. Here there is dynamic code in while loop like:

```
$html_img = '<div class="sch_rel_img">';
if(count($node_img)>1)       
{
    $html_img .='<link href="'.base_path().drupal_get_path('module','demonz').'/css/jquery.bxslider.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" charset="utf-8"/>';    
    $html_img .='<script src="'.base_path().'sites/default/themes/demonz/js/jquery-1.4.2.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>';

    $html_img .='<script src="'.base_path().drupal_get_path('module','pubclub').'/js/jquery.searchres_bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>';

    $html_img .='<script type="text/javascript" src="'.base_path().drupal_get_path('module','pubclub').'/js/search_carousel.js" charset="utf-8"></script>';

    //$html_img .="<input type='hidden' name='nid' id='nid' value='".$nid."' />";
    //$car = 1;
    //$html_img .='<div class="schnext" id="schnext_'.$nid.'"></div><ul class="carousel_'.$nid.'">';    
    $html_img .='<div class="schnext" id="schnext"></div><ul class="carousel" id="carousel_'.$nid.'">';
    foreach($node_img as $img)
    {
        $image = $img['filepath'];        
        $html_img .="<li>";
        $html_img .="<img src='".$image."' width='98%' height='96%' />";
        $html_img .="</li>";    

    }
    /*$html_img .= "<li><img src='".base_path()."sites/default/files/images/events/17b9e1fb62623361831924370675857fe73225b8/big-event.jpg' width='98%' height='96%' /></li>";
    $html_img .= "<li><img src='".base_path()."sites/default/files/images/events/17b9e1fb62623361831924370675857fe73225b8/innquizitive_thursday_screen_ad.jpg' width='98%' height='96%' /></li>";*/
    //$html_img .='</ul><div class="schprev" id="schprev_'.$nid.'"></div>';
    $html_img .='</ul><div class="schprev" id="schprev"></div>';
}
$html_img .='</div>';
```

And my bxslider script is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var slider = $(".carousel").bxSlider({
        mode:'horizontal', 
        auto:false,
        pager:false,
        moveSlides:1,
        nextSelector: '#schnext',
        prevSelector: '#schprev'
        /*nextText: 'Onward →',
        prevText: '← Go back'*/
    });
</script>
```

how to implement this thing to get multiple carousel in one page. I can't understand how to build up the js file of bxslider in dynamic way as well as above php script's code.

I tried this thing with `$('.carousel').each(function() { slidercode });` but not desired result.

If any one knows about this type of solution, please help me.

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

As you have muiltiple DIVs with a unique carousel_* ID just use them for the selector.

```
$('#carousel_1').bxslider({ ... });
$('#carousel_2').bxslider({ ... });
...
```

Or if they all have the same options:

```
$('.carousel').each(function(index,item) {
    $(item).bxslider({ ... });
});
```

Multiple slideshows are also explained in the [docs from bxslider](http://bxslider.com/examples/multiple-slideshows).

Comment: This page no longer exists, use this link from the wayback machine to see the doc: https://web.archive.org/web/20170623132149/http://bxslider.com:80/examples/multiple-slideshows